# Developing a NavigationBar Based application including one Open GL View : How?

Tags: cocoa-touch, opengl-es

My question starts from a problem :

I started a project in Xcode : a Navigation Bar based one (with a TableView).
Then I added a few views, through IB or programmatically... which works perfectly fine.

Then, I decided to write my Own ViewClass, inherited from UIView, called OpenGlView (based on the view provided by Basic OpenGlES project in XCode), and its `OpenGlViewController` (inherited from `UIViewController`).

This works fine until I try to push the view Controller into my navBar: then I receive a **"EXC__ BAD __ACCESS"**. I can't understand why it is ok whith any view but the one used for display OpenGL content...

And I actually have no idea how I can manage to develop a NavBar based App including a View displaying OpenGL contents... any idea?

(I also tried to add the `OpenGlView` as a subView of a basic `UIView` previously added to the NavigationBar, but I received the same error).

**In the RootController :**

```
OpenGlViewController *glvController;

if (glvController == nil) 
{
    glvController = [[OpenGlViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Gl View" bundle:nil];
    glvController.title = @"GL View";
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:glvController animated:YES];
```

**in the OpenGlViewController :**

```
- (void)loadView {
OpenGlView * view;
view = [[OpenGlView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
self.view = view;
[view release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's localized to your OpenGL view, the crash may be the result of not properly initializing OpenGL items inside your view.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260391/why-does-calling-glmatrixmodeglprojection-give-me-excbadaccess-in-an-iphone#266005) for my recommendations on a potentially similar problem.